# Kafka consumers unable to send heartbeat but receives messages

Tags: .net, azure, apache-kafka, bitnami, confluent-platform

I'm using a Kafka Cluster from Bitnami on Azure (https://bitnami.com/stack/kafka/cloud/azure). It is a single node cluster with broker on one VM and Zookeeper on another. I have enabled the ports 9090 and 2181.

I have .Net Core WebApps running on azure with Confluent .NET Client (v1.0.0) for Kafka. The WebApps have producers and consumers configured.

The problem I'm facing is, soon after starting the web app, the consumer fails due to **heartbeat expiration**. But it is able to receive some messages from the producer in the meanwhile. Even if I simply start one Consumer only, it automatically fails after SessionTimeoutMs due to heartbeat expiration.

I'm unable to understand why the heartbeat expires (while messages are being received by the consumer). Does it happen on a separate port? If I set the SessionTimeoutMs = 300000 (max), it expires after exactly 5 minutes.

Server log (when I add a consumer in a WebApp - notice that the heartbeat expires within 16 seconds):

```
[2019-05-22 17:57:42,302] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Preparing to rebalance group test-consumer-group-new2 in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 4 (__consumer_offsets-40) (reason: Adding new member rdkafka-03f8db78-4f74-4cb2-9389-bb949c53281c) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2019-05-22 17:57:42,303] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Stabilized group test-consumer-group-new2 generation 5 (__consumer_offsets-40) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2019-05-22 17:57:42,349] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Assignment received from leader for group test-consumer-group-new2 for generation 5 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2019-05-22 17:57:58,403] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Member rdkafka-03f8db78-4f74-4cb2-9389-bb949c53281c in group test-consumer-group-new2 has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2019-05-22 17:57:58,403] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Preparing to rebalance group test-consumer-group-new2 in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 5 (__consumer_offsets-40) (reason: removing member rdkafka-03f8db78-4f74-4cb2-9389-bb949c53281c on heartbeat expiration) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2019-05-22 17:57:58,404] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Group test-consumer-group-new2 with generation 6 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-40) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

My server.properties:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://40.X.X.X:9092
```

The consumer's config:

```
var conf = new ConsumerConfig
{
    GroupId = "test-consumer-group-new2",
    BootstrapServers = "40.X.X.X:9092",
    SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.Plaintext,
    SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain,
    SaslUsername = "user",
    SaslPassword = "<passowrd>"
}
```

I also do not understand the old/new Generations in Kafka and could not find documentation on the same. Can anyone please shed some light on it? Thanks.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. We configure Kafka using default values. You will need to tune the parameters to work with your application. If you find better values to configure Kafka with, please let us know so we can improve the solution based on your feedback.

Comment: @JotaMartos even with the default values, do you know why the heartbeat is expiring over the network? (On same machine as broker, producers and consumers work well).

Comment: tracking this here: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/966

Answer (score 0):

`max.poll.records` - may need to be reduced;

pay attention for `heartbeat.interval.ms` - the value must be set lower than `session.timeout.ms`, but typically should be set no higher than 1/3 of that value

Comment: Yes, all of these are set to their default values.